# registartion form on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, registration

I am trying to hide wordpress login\register\lostpassword\logout forms and redirect to my own pages
I have tried this

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

function possibly_redirect(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
  wp_redirect('http://google.com/');
  exit();
 }
}
```

but this will redirect all pages to 1 page i want to edit individuals like registration and lost password each to redirect elsewhere so I tried this

```
/* שינוי עמוד התחברות *//**
/*התחברות*/
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) || //  this is line 33
    else wp_redirect( home_url('/%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8/') ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
/*התנתקות*/
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='logout') ||   // in case of LOGOUT
    else wp_redirect( home_url() ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
/*איפוס יסמא*/
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='confirm') ||   // in case of LOST PASSWORD
    else wp_redirect( home_url('/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90/') ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
/*הרשם*/
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='registered') ) return;    // in case of REGISTER
    else wp_redirect( home_url('/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94/') ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
```

dont get me wrong I have no idea how to write php I took this from some searches and tried to play around so it works... but it does not work... sometimes it shows an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/content/11/9595411/html/luachmodaot/wp-content/themes/boozurk/functions.php on line 33
```

can someone help me out with this please?

Comment: remove `||` from between `if and else`...

Comment: i have done that and it still giving me the error and my website is down because of it... :(

Comment: you havent defined that what the code has to do if the **if condition is true**....

Comment: this code looked like this before:
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) ||   
      ( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='logout') ||   // in case of LOGOUT
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='confirm') ||   // in case of LOST PASSWORD
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='registered') ) return;    
    else wp_redirect( home_url() ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

Comment: than you need to do some rnd on php.. because without having knowledge of php how would you work in wordpress...

Comment: well... i plan to... but till then can you help me please?

Comment: As Nishant already suggested, I would suggest you to replace `||` with `{}` and then check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below for correct php code syntax, but i've no idea if it will work based on what you have given. Are you creating a theme yourself or modifying a theme?

you had a number of errors after the one you posted. 
Basically your if statement syntax was wrong - should be if(you exist && you == you) {do this please;} else {ok do this instead;} -- if you mess up the brackets you get an error. btw you dont need to check isset $var && $var == something, just check its equal to something, if its not, it will fail.

why do you want to redirect away from the pages? if its something as simple as styling you can do something like this https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-a-custom-wordpress-login-page/. if you dont know php, it might be a place to start rather than creating your own method

```
function possibly_redirect(){
global $pagenow;
if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) {  //  this is line 33 - the error was telling you had a open statement....syntax for if statement :  if(    ) {      } else {     }   
    wp_redirect( home_url('/%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8/') ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
}

if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( $_GET['action']=='logout') { // in case of LOGOUT
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
    }
}

if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( $_GET['checkemail']=='confirm') {   // in case of LOST PASSWORD
         wp_redirect( home_url('/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90/') ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
    }
}

if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( $_GET['checkemail']=='registered' ) { //return;---> use in function only!!!!!!!!
    wp_redirect( home_url('/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94/') ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
       }
    }
    }

    add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for your effort! this was very helpful. i pasted the code and it worked! just 1 little problem is when clicking on the logout link... it redirects to the homepage without logging out...

Comment: regarding the plugin you shows... its does not help me since i want the login page to be inside the site like not going to a blank page to login... just a login and password within one of the sites pages...

Comment: i fixed the log out issue. The link above is not a plugin, its a tutorial on how to modify the login page that comes with wordpress. Its a good way to learn some of the functions with login/logout ...

Comment: thanks! you the man! ill check out the link see what i can learn thanks again.